# Client-side calculated model in Google App maker does not work for SuggestBox widget

Tags: google-app-maker

A Client-side calculated model in Google App Maker was used to populate the options in the SuggestBox widget. This was done by assigning the Model of the Suggest Box Query Options to the this client side model. When I type something in the widget it would display the following error.

**TypeError: Cannot call method "Na" of undefined.**

I used this model on a List widget and it showed all of it's content. I used the SuggestBox widget with a Cloud SQL model and that worked fine as well.

What is the issue here and how can I make this work?

Comment: Please post Client side calculated model code.

Comment: I deleted the code and found a workaround which was less convenient. In the code I iterated a datasource and returned that data as I wanted. I tested it with a List widget and it worked. Actually what I wanted to do with the SuggestBox widget was to make the return value a record. This could only be done in the Suggest Box Query Options. And in that you could only use a model and not a datasource.